# How to check valid redirected URL and its response code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check valid URL using pattern and get its response code.

Like:

1)

```
var url =  "https://google.com"
```

Output: It is valid URL so you can redirect to page.

2)

```
var url =  "https://notfoundnotfound.com"
```

Output: It is invalid URL and redirects to not found the page.

Is there any option or lib for checking right redirect URL?

Comment: My bet is you can find a third party service to send string to and get it validated

Comment: You need to validate your url using server side.

Comment: Can you give any type of reference for the lib?

Answer (score 0):

Becasue of Origin Policy you can't check if you get valid response (200 response code) using AJAX for every url, so you will need to create server side code that will check if you get 200 code from url and call ajax to your server side script and get response if url is valid.